how to solve the "unable to connect to server" in smowcode?
When I try verifying, downloading or uploading binaries, the top notification bar in Smowcode shows "Verification/Upload failed"  with error bar showing "unable to connect to server".
Unable to solve it.
I tried clicking "retry".
#smowcode


Spamming with irrelevant or overly generic tags is ill- advised.

The issue is caused due to internet connection in your computer.
Solutions would be:

Change the network channel (WiFi, Ethernet etc)
Check if google.com works.
Use a WiFi dongle if your WiFi is not working.

You can click "try again" on the dialog once internet is connected.
